# Autocomplete don't work when it get loaded via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I have a upload-file-form in `home.php`. When a file is uploaded successfully the `home.php` loads the `upload.php` where I have a form there the user can write the information about the mp3 file, info like artist name and things like that. I want to implement the Autocomplete script by jQuery. But the autocomplete don't work when it get loaded through javascript code but it work when I visit the page upload.php. What can be the problem?

**Home.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-6">
    <script src="src/script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="iso-8859-6"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin-top:-60px;">
    <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
        <div>
            <input class="ufile" type="file" name="ufile" id="ufile" accept="audio/*" onchange="loadFile(this)" />
            <input type="button" class="button" id="upload_button" value="ارفع ملف صوتي" onclick="inputCheck()" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <div style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">
        <div id="upload_response"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Upload.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-6">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            var availableTags = ["html",  "php"];
            $("#artistInput").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <form name="saveForm" action="upload.php" method="post" onSubmit="return(infoCheck(this))">
            <input class="uploadinput" style="width:430px;" name="artist" id="artistInput">
            <input type="submit" class="button" style="color:white;margin-left:5px;width:160px;background:url(images/red_gradient.jpg)" value="حفظ" name="saveInfo" />
            <input type="reset" class="button" style="color:black;width:168px;background:url(images/yellow_gradient.jpg)" value="إعادة تعيين">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Script.js**

```
function uploadFinish(e) { // upload successfully finished
    var oUploadResponse = document.getElementById('upload_response');
    oUploadResponse.innerHTML = e.target.responseText;
    oUploadResponse.style.display = 'block';
    $("#upload").animate({
        height: '765px'
    }, 350);
    $('#errormessage').slideUp('fast');
}
```

Comment: "when it get loaded through javascript code" How is it loaded? Inserted in home.php with `$.load()`?

Comment: `var oUploadResponse = document.getElementById('upload_response');
    oUploadResponse.innerHTML = e.target.responseText;` This code show how it appears on the home.php through javascript @Bigood

Comment: Where in your code is script.js loaded?

Comment: `script.js` is always loaded on the `home.php` but it loads the `upload.php` when the uploading of the file is finished. @Nemothefish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing the script before the DOM element is ready.

You can do several different things to solve it, for example:

1. Load your script at the bottom of the page
2. Move your script inside document ready event, so the DOM element is available
     `$(document).ready(function() { -your script here- });`

Comment: Good solution. I tried to do it like you suggested but i dident work but i used the `$(document).ready(function() { -your script here- });`and added it to the `uploadFinish(e)`function.

Comment: Have you cheked your browser's JavaScript console? You must be doing something wrong. `$(document).ready(function() {})` is the "universal solution which everybody uses". The code inside the braces is executed when the page has finished loading, and it's cross browser: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ The console can show you what you are doing wrong: a typo, jquery missing or whatever... I don't know, but this shouldn't fail

Comment: My fault. I added the code in `upload.php` but i should add it to `home.php`. Thanks it works very fine now. @JotaBe

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax to use auto complete type plug-in..

```
<style>

label._tags {
    padding:5px 10px;
    margin:0px;
    border:solid thin #ccc;
    border-radius:3px;
    display: inline-block;
}

label._tags span {
    padding:2px 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    color:#FFF;
    border-radius:700px;
    font-family:"calibri",verdana,serif;
    background-color:teal;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">



var request;
var tag=new Array();
function getXMLObject(){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        return(new XMLHttpRequest);
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        return(new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp"));
    }else{
        return (null);
    }
}


function getCategory(){


    var address="Ajax_testing";
     request=getXMLObject();
     var data=document.getElementById("multitag").value;

     var nwadd=address+"?text="+data;


     request.onreadystatechange=showResultsubject;
     request.open("GET",nwadd,true);
     request.send();
}


function close()
{

     var y=document.getElementById("p");



    var myNode = document.getElementById("p");
        while (myNode.firstChild) {
         myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
        }
     y.setAttribute("style","dispaly:none;");




}

function removetag(id)
{

     var y=document.getElementById("l");

     var z=document.getElementById(id.substr(3));

     tag.pop();

         y.removeChild(z);






}
  function gettag(id){


     tag.push(id);
     var f="";

     for (var i=0;i<tag.length;i++)
     {

         var s="<label class='_tags' id='"+tag[i]+"'>"+tag[i]+"<span><a  id='tag"+tag[i]+"' onclick='removetag(this.id)'>X</a></span> </label>";

          f=f.concat(s);
     }

     document.getElementById("l").innerHTML=f;
    }






       <tr>
            <td>Keyword :

             </td>

            <td><input type="text" id="multitag"  name="multitag" onkeyup="getCategory()" onclick="close()">
            <div id="l">

            </div>



           <div id="p" style="display: none;z-index:11;" >

           </div> 
           </td> 
           </tr>
```